# What is a bachelor of Engineering (Honours) and Master of Engineering

Tags: university, australia

Context: I am high school student in Australia and currently applying for university 2021. I am interested in engineering and I came across this "bachelor OF Engineering (Honours) and Master of Engineering" program provided by University of Queensland.

I always thought that you need a bachelor's degree to get a master’s degree? It seems to me that this program integrates Master's coursework with bachelor's? Does that mean that if I successfully completed this program in 5 years, I will graduate with a bachelor and a master degree?

UQ program link - https://future-students.uq.edu.au/study/programs/bachelor-engineering-honours-and-master-engineering-2350

Comment: looks so. But it is not very clear. I would email and ask for further information.

Comment: Could be university specific, but there are honors programs at US universities that offer a straightforward 4+1 path to a bachelors/masters degree (source - looking at universities with my kids, and hiring summer students from such institutions).

Comment: 5 years seems about right, Hons in 3 and Masters in 2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you graduate this course you will get both a bachelor's of engineering (honours) and a masters of engineering, however this will take longer (as in 5 years rather than the normal 4 years for an engineering degree).

If you look at the AQF (Australian Qualification Framework) level you'll see that its level 9, which is a masters degree. Level 7 is bachelor degree, level 8 is bachelor (honours degree) and level 10 is PhD.

Normally (in the Australian framework) you get a bachelor degree in 3 years then you can do an honours degree on top of that which is an extra year. Rather than doing a honours degree you could instead do a masters degree which was often 1.5 to 2 years long. Some universities only offer masters degrees and for some universities a masters degree is essentially some upper year course from the bachelor degree plus an honours degree (though this also depends on the field). After either an honours (which is sometimes mixed with the bachelor degree) or a masters you can apply for a PhD, however places in Europe don't always recognise an honours degree as it would be recognised in Australia.

This degree in particular started about 10 years ago the University of Queensland started a combined masters/bachelors course for engineering (I know some people from the first cohort). This is essentially the bachelor of engineering course plus the requirements for a masters, including a research thesis which you don't need for the bachelor of engineering (honours).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I realised that normal bachelor (honours) degree requires 4 years https://future-students.uq.edu.au/study/programs/bachelor-engineering-honours-2455 and master of engineering degree requires an additional of 2 years. https://future-students.uq.edu.au/study/programs/master-engineering-5674. Does that mean that if I select this program, it is going to more work-extensive ?

Comment: I can't really answer that question since I only know people who took those degrees and did a different degree myself. In both cases you will only take 4 courses each semester (which is equal to 8 units), though some courses count as more than one. If you go down to 'what you'll study' and click on 'See all courses in this program' you can see the courses you have to take/what elective options are available. There is a little bit of overlap between the two courses so I think they used that and dropped some electives to shave off the sixth year.

Comment: Hi NA McMahon, it seems like they changed the AQF level down to 8????

Comment: I suspect either you were accidentally looking at the wrong page or  a temporary mistake on their end, it shows me AQF 9 when I click on the link in your original question

Comment: Hi NA McMahon, yeah no worries (Thanks for replying). They changed it back after I had contacted them.